# How to loop over table variable to make specific calculations?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, table-variable

If i have a table variable like that how to loop over this var to make some processing :

```
DECLARE @userData TABLE(
                                    userId int NOT NULL,
                                    dayDate datetime NOT NULL,
                                    transIn datetime NULL,
                                    transOut datetime NULL,
                                    attIn datetime NULL,
                                    attOut datetime NULL,
                                    MissionIn datetime NOT NULL,
                                    MissionOut datetime NOT NULL,
                                    empState varchar(10) NULL
                                   );


                INSERT INTO @userData
                SELECT userid, trans_date,transtime_in,transtime_out,att_start_time,att_end_time,@Mission_fromdatetime,@Mission_todatetime,day_flag
                FROM datatable_o a
                WHERE a.userid = @userid AND a.trans_date = @date ORDER BY  transtime_in ;
```

---

According to the comments the Whole case :

If the work starts at : `att_start_time` and ends at `att_end_time` (work period]

Every employee could check -in and check-out many times in the same date so we could follow him .
the check-in  stored in `transtime_in`
and check-out stored in `transtime_out`

and i have `day_flag` so i could know the day is 'W' work day or 'E' weekend

Now considering all these information in addition to the `emp_num ,date`

I want to calc for the an employee `External mission over time` :

I have four cases :

1. No check-in-out && Not work day [weekend]   So the employee
   should take all the mission period as overtime
2. No check-in-out && Work day [Absent]   so the employee should
   take only the mission period out of the work period
3. There are check-in-outs && Not work day [week end]   so the
   employee should take only the mission period out of these
   check-ins-outs
4. There are check-ins-outs && work day   so the employee should take
   only the mission period out of these check-ins-outs and at the same
   time out of work period .

Example :

```
emp_num     date         att_start   att_end    mission-in  mission-out
  672      2015-3-4       07:05:00    13:30:00   12:12:00    20:00:00
```

---

```
emp_num      date         trans_in     trans_out 

 672       2015-3-4       06:54:00     11:10:00
 672       2015-3-4       12:00:00     14:05:00
```

Comment: What kind of processing are you trying to do? SQL generally doesn't like loops. It's better to handle the data as a set. If you give more detail it may be possible to avoid using a loop, improving the performance of the resulting query.

Comment: You should also be aware that tables inherently have no order. Since there's no limiting performed in your `SELECT` query (such as a `TOP` or `FETCH` clause), the `ORDER BY` is completely pointless.

Comment: @Aidan i want to make calculation and insert in another table

Comment: @just_name - that clarification doesn't help at all. We mean what, *specific* calculation(s) are you trying to perform? Your current approach seems to be very *procedural* (first I'll do this and put the results in a table, then I'll do that and put those results in a table, then I'll do the next thing...). SQL works best when you can construct a single query that describes *what you want*, not *how to do it* and then let the query optimizer work out how best to achieve that result.

Comment: @just_name The question you should be asking is "How do I do this calculation?" An insert or a loop is easy enough to do on it's own, what we need to know to be able to help you is exactly what it is that you need the loop _for_. With that in mind, what we need to know is what kind of calculation are you trying to do?

Comment: for example i want to check that `(MissionIn,MissionOut)` in the period of `transIn,transOut` if not i will get that period and insert it in db

Comment: If that's what you want to do.... write a query based on that logic and insert the results into a table. Based on your description, we will assume you don't need a loop, whereas you are assuming you do. If you explain what you'r trying to do maybe we can stop assuming and start helping.

Comment: @just_name please feel free to give a feedback on [below answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29512223/3208640)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I write the whole case , could u suggest a solution instead of looping and many if conditions ?thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through your table by taking help from a copy of that table:

with regard to your question assuming your table is:

```
DECLARE @userData TABLE(
                         userId int NOT NULL,
                         /*Other fields*/
                        );
```

and the data of your table is:

```
INSERT INTO @userData
/*A SELECT or values*/
```

now create a copy of your table as:

```
DECLARE @userData_2 TABLE(
                         userId int NOT NULL,
                         /*Structure should be the same as @userData*/
                        );
INSERT INTO @userData_2
SELECT * FROM  @userData
```

now you can do the loop and do whatever you want:

```
DECLARE @userId INT
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @userData_2)
BEGIN
SET @userId=(SELECT TOP 1 userId FROM @userData)
/*

DO YOUR TRANSACTION HERE

*/
DELETE FROM @userData_2 WHERE userId=@userID
END
```

**NOTICE:** this assumes the userId is unique, if not then you need to have a unique field, or use a composite fields instead of userId.